# How to save two canvas image with one button Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am creating a small project to allow the user to modify two canvas and upload the two canvas at the same time. In order to do that, the submit button should allow the user to download both of the canvas they created. But I don't know why, any time I add a second image to download with the button, it does not work.

This is my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { fabric } from "fabric";

var mainCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
var secCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");

// Add a rectange
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: "#ff0000",
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  id: 1
});

mainCanvas.add(rect);
secCanvas.add(rect);

// Add a circle
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: "#ffff00",
  radius: 50,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center",
  id: 2
});

mainCanvas.add(circle);

// Add a text
var text = new fabric.IText("Type here...", {
  fontSize: 27,
  top: 10,
  left: 10
});

mainCanvas.add(text);

// Add an image
fabric.Image.fromURL(
  "https://placekitten.com/200/303",
  function(img) {
    var image = img.set({
      selectable: false,
      evented: false,
      left: 230
    });

    mainCanvas.add(image);
    mainCanvas.sendToBack(image);

    mainCanvas.renderAll();
  },
  { crossOrigin: "anonymous" }
);



var saveBoth = document.getElementById("save2");
saveBoth.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function(e) {
    this.href = secCanvas.toDataURL({
      format: "png"
    });
    this.href = mainCanvas.toDataURL({
      format: "png"
    });

    this.download = "secCanvas.png";
    this.download = "mainCanvas.png";
  },
  false
);
```

When I tried running this code, it only saves 1 image as canvas, the first one.
I tried changing it to:

```
this.download="secCanvas.png","mainCanvas.png";
```

But this only brings me to an error.
My question is,
how do I get it to download both of these 2 canvas with only a single click of the button.

Comment: Doing `this.href = ...` and `this.download = ...` twice, is of course overwriting those variables. // Not sure how this actually works, having trouble to find that download functionality described in their docs to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe downloading works, but it only works with 1 file

Comment: Yes of course, because you are overwriting both those properties immediately. You would need to use two separate links, and then try and trigger a click event on them. Not sure if that will even work though, or whether the one download will cancel out the other in that situation. There is no real mechanism to figure out when one such download has finished, so triggering the second one only after the first one was already handled, might not really be possible.